# moz-transform scale decrease div size problem

Tags: css, firefox, gecko, css-transforms

I'm having problems with mozilla moz-transform scale property.
I'm looking for a replacement of the zoom property, which works fine in everything except firefox.

When I want to shrink the div, its "content" does shrink, but the size of the container stays the same, leaving a big gap around other content.

Is there any way I can force the container size to decrease as well?

To clarify I put a simple example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/VXmnm/15/).
Open it in chrome and firefox, you will see the difference.

Comment: Container does shrink in FF (at least in 3.6), it's just that inside div also shrinks to half the size. With that css container is 150X150 in FF and inner div is 50x50. If you set inner div to have -moz-transform: scale(2); than container is 150x150 and inner div remains 100x100.

Comment: Hmm, I'll check it out. In 4.0.1 it's not fine. The problem is in the "Something after" text, which should be just under the div (no empty space), not the inner div

Comment: Ah, I see. Not sure how to go about it. You can use  -moz-transform-origin:left bottom; for test div but then you get empty space on top )))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only solution I have got so far is to wrap it all in another div container, with fixed height.

Not really what I was looking for, but until someone finds a better solution, I think its the only way to go.

Comment: Thanks for -moz-transform-origin:left top; attribute in your exaple. It helped me a lot :)

Comment: Can you please explain more carefully what you mean? We have the same problem! @ZolaKt

Comment: It was a long time ago, I don't have the exact example. But if I remember right, you wrap the problematic div in another div. Set fixed height on that parent element. The div inside still breaks layout with extra space, but you put overflow: hidden on the parent so the breaking is not visible. It is a hack, not so pretty, but it works

Answer (score -1):

Instead of mixing `zoom` and `-moz-transform`, why not use `-webkit-transform` for Chrome? Then you can adjust the height equally on all browsers.

Comment: because zoom takes care of ie also, not just chrome. yes, fixed height seems like the only way to go. another container which wraps it all, with fixed height. the problematic div is still too big, but it doesn't break the layout